# Does anything bad happen when throwing from validateValueCallback?

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

When registering a dependency property, the [overload of `Register` that accepts a validation callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501.aspx) can be used.

If that validation callback returns `false` for a value, assigning that value to the dependency property will fail and an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) will be thrown, complaining about the invalid property value.

Now, while `ArgumentException` is an appropriate type in some situations, there are some specialized exception types that should be used in certain situations. In particular, I am declaring a property of an `enum` type, for which the proper way to handle unsupported values is throwing an [`InvalidEnumArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception.aspx). What is more, I am implementing an interface that exhibits that `enum` property as a CLR property and, in the doc comments for that property, requires an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` to be thrown for invalid values.

The three solutions that I am seeing are:

- Change the interface docs to allow a more general exception type. *This is untidy and I consider unacceptable as a "solution" as it defeats the purpose of having **and documenting** specialized exception types. Otherwise, I could just as well write [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) anywhere in my docs and leave it up to API users to guess and/or try which one will actually be thrown.*
- Return `false` from the validate value callback registered with the dependency property (thus causing an `ArgumentException` when changing the property value via [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx), and throwing an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` in the setter of the CLR property wrapper. *This is untidy for a different reason, as CLR property wrappers should not contain any logic of their own, other than calling [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx)/[`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx). It would seem inconsistent to have the dependency property itself behave differently than when accessing it through its CLR property setter.*
- Throw an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` in the validate value callback instead of returning `false`. *This is the solution I am using now.*

I have tried the third solution and it seems to work. The only drawback might be losing the default exception message, which seems like the lesser evil though.

My question is: **Does throwing like this from the validate value callback have any side-effects that I am not aware of and that will get me (or rather, my code) into trouble?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're fine throwing a more specific exception from your validation callback. Just reflecting over the WPF code, it looks like this pseudocode:

```
if (!validateValueCallback(newValue))
    throw new ArgumentException();
```

So, if your validation callback throws, I can't see how it would cause any issues.

Comment: The actual code looks quite a bit more complicated than that, but it does boil down to what you wrote, without any specific precautions in the cases where exceptions are thrown. So, it was a good idea to check like that, accepted :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks for this Abe. MSDN states [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.100).aspx#Validation_Callbacks) that "If the validation callback is invoked by any of these operations, and returns false, then an exception will be raised." but it doesn't say what type of exception is raised!